# What could cause a culture to cover up all their body openings?

Tags: culture, clothing

I noticed that on the beach western people tend to cover their butt, genitals. But for some weird reason they leave a lot of other openings exposed. For example the belly button and the arm pits containing lymphatic sweat glands. In female bathing suits the lymphatic sweat glands in the groin area are also frequently exposed. Meanwhile arabs at the beach wear long gowns covering almost the entire body.

What could cause a culture to cover **all** the body openings (except the eyes), exposing them only if something needs to enter or exit of a body opening? I mean mouth, nostrils, ears, arm pits glands, nipples, belly button, groin pits glands, genitals, butt. In this fictional culture, all these body openings should be covered at all times with a thing non-transparent cloth, even as a ritual only, except when a body opening is directly in use.

Even though it is just a ritual, what could be the cause why such a ritual was established? Maybe to prevent the spread of infectious diseases, similar to face masks?

Comment: The history of fashion is entirely cultural. Western social mores in the 1800s also covered up the majority of the body. Modern social mores are the consequence of the mid-60s sexual revolution and the resource shortages of WWII. Covering the entire body in the Muslim world is religious (and non-practitioners often suggest that it's purpose is rooted more in gender control than religion). If you're just musing over the issue, this is the wrong forum to ask the Q. If you're building a world, this Q is opinion-based until you tell us how you'll judge a best answer.

Comment: @JBH I'm trying to create a believable non-western non-arab culture.

Comment: OK, but how will you judge a best answer? We need to convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609).

Comment: Auguste Racinet, [*Le costume historique*](https://archive.org/details/lecostumehistori01raci), Paris, 1888. Six volumes, five hundred illustrations. The link goes to volume 1, freely available at Archive.org; the URLs of volumes 2 to 6 are what's expected. You are welcome. (And European women wore veils covering their faces in several places at several times. History is long, and varied; people wore different clothes in different places at different times.)

Comment: Sand. Mosquitoes. No ozone layer, so the sun is more dangerous. There's endless good reasons to cover yourself up.

Answer (score 4):

**It is always freaking cold.**

[image: scarf]

[source](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-42199200)

It is always cold where these folks are.  Even inside, because they are ok with it being cold so they don't crank the heat.  They cope by wrapping up and they stay wrapped up.  Even when it is not that cold, it feels weird for these folks to not be wrapped up. Like you or I would feel weird strutting around naked from the waist down.
Or I would, anyway.